# I need to make the title of the page dynamic in my custom plugin

Tags: customization, title

```
// Our callback to create the contact form page.
function gym_contact_create_form() {
  $form = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'Gym Contact Page' ),
    'post_name'    => 'gym-contact-form',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
  );
  // Check if page exists
  $page = get_page_by_path('gym-contact-form');
  if ($page == NULL) {
    // Create a page upon creation.
    wp_insert_post( $form );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dynamic how? When and why does it change? Where's the title supposed to come from? Where is this code run?

Comment: Hi Jacob Peattie, I am building a custom form plugin and I have gathered code that I have seen in several tutorials, it turns out that this code fragment makes me static the name of the page, that is if in the admin of wordpress the name Gym Contact Page appears and if I change the template in html is not displayed it is as if it were strictly necessary to call so the contact page